# Apple APNS access via Corporate Proxy

Tags: proxy, apple-push-notifications

Am new to Apple APNS and had a query: Is it possible to connect to Apple APNS (gateway.push.apple.com, feedback.push.apple.com) via a corporate proxy?

Have a deployment environment where we have the following tiers

Front end web tier (having apache web server)
Application tier (hosting the application that needs to connect to APNS)
Data tier (database)

Requirement is for the application on the application tier to connect to APNS.. is it mandatory for having a direct connection opened between application server and Apple APNS or is it possible to route this traffic via the Front end web tier (Apache - as a proxy)?

Application uses java code to connect to APNS.

Any pointers would help..

Answer (score 1):

Device to APNS is on 5223, and is not proxyable.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's possible if you proxy allows ssl connexions and route the traffic on 443 port.

Comment: Connection to APNS is on port 2195 and 2196 and as per Apple documentation, this is not HTTP. Am unsure if this traffic can be routed via Apache.. hence the query.